# Find column number with merged cells vba

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to find the column with a specific header in a table where almost all the headers are merged. Here is an example with dummy data of what my table looks like:

[image: Table with headers merged]

I have tried either looking in row 1 and 2 (range `A1:XFD1` and `A2:XFD2`), but it seems that vba cannot find the column I am looking for:

```
Sub getColumn()
Dim ColNum As Integer
On Error Resume Next
ColNum = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD1").Find(What:="Unit Cost", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
MsgBox ("Column number is: " & ColNum)
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change your

```
.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD1")
```

to

```
.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD2")
```

Since you're searching for 2 rows indeed

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub getColumn()

        Dim ColNum      As Long
        Dim rCell       As Range
        Dim rRange      As Range

        On Error Resume Next

        Set rRange = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:XFD1")

        For Each rCell In rRange
            If rCell.MergeArea.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                msgBox (rCell.Column) 'consider debug.print rCell.column
            End If
        Next rCell

    End Sub
```

I have not tested it, but it should work... :)
Pretty much you simply loop through your range and check each column whether it is merged. Then you give MsgBox.

Answer (score 1):

since `Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` is the same as `ActiveWorkbook` and this latter is the *default* implicit workbook qualification, you can simply code the following helper function:

```
Function GetColumn(stringToFind As String) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetColumn = Worksheets("Data").Rows("1:2").Find(What:=stringToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column
End Function
```

to be exploited in your "Main" sub as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim colNum As Long

    colNum = GetColumn("Unit Cost") '<--| returns 0 if "Unit Cost" is not found
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your column and row

```
Sub findHeader()      
    For i = 1 To 5
       If Cells(1, i).Value = "Unit Cost" Then
          MsgBox Cells(1, i).Value
       End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Match` locates your *unit cost* column.

```
dim colm as variant
with activesheet
    colm = application.match("unit cost", .rows(1), 0)
    if not iserror(colm) then
        debug.print colm   'column as number
    else
        colm = application.match("unit cost", .rows(2), 0)
        if not iserror(colm) then
            debug.print colm   'column as number
        else
            debug.print "not found"
        end if
    end if
end if
```